# Single word for "When you're using too much of a good thing at once."

Tags: single-word-requests

What is one word that means "When you're using too much of a good thing at once"?

Comment: This is the community defined guideline for Single Word Requests - "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE DEMONSTRATING HOW THE WORD WOULD BE USED". Please include an example as appropriate.

Comment: Also ***wasteful***

Answer (score 3):

The first word to my mind was [**overindulge**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overindulge).

> to indulge to excess

The noun form, the action of overindulging, would be **overindulgence**.